# Provider State is not Updating

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm developing the flutter app which can play audio. Audio is fetching from firebase and playing perfectly but the problem is that when begin to play audio and exit from that screen, again, revisiting that screen, it won't update its state(seekbar, play/pause button, time passed).

usually what happens that when I have implemented local state when audio is been load then duration of the music is updated and I' started playing then it is updating slider(seekbar) and current position of the song. But after I have used Provider it is not updating completely.

below is the widget code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:app/model/PlayerState.dart';
import 'package:app/stories/get_stories.dart';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/error_alert.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';

class PlayingStory extends StatefulWidget {
  final String story;
  final String episode;
  final String playLink;
  final String poster;

  const PlayingStory(
      {Key? key,
        required this.story,
        required this.episode,
        required this.playLink,
        required this.poster})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PlayingStoryState();
}

class PlayingStoryState extends State<PlayingStory> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  double _value = 0.0;
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late bool isPlaying;
  late AppLifecycleState state;
  late String episode = widget.episode;

  // void _showChoices(BuildContext context) {
  //
  //   // GetStories().updateStoryList(widget.story,context);
  //   var nextEpisode = GetStories().fetchNextEpisodes(widget.story);
  //
  //   OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
  //   OverlayEntry? choice;
  //
  //   final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  //   final height = size.height;
  //   final width = size.width;
  //
  //   choice = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
  //     print("_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ OVERLAY CALLED _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_");
  //     return Scaffold(
  //       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  //       body: Center(
  //         child: Padding(
  //           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.035, vertical: height * 0.06),
  //           child: ColoredBox(
  //             color: const Color(0xff838080),
  //             child: BackdropFilter(
  //               filter: ImageFilter.blur(
  //                 sigmaY: 8.0,
  //                 sigmaX: 8.0,
  //               ),
  //               child: Center(
  //                 child: ListView(
  //                   children: [
  //
  //                     FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(
  //                       future: nextEpisode,
  //                       builder: (context, snapshot) {
  //                         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  //                           return const Center(
  //                             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  //                           );
  //                         }
  //
  //                         final nxteps = snapshot.data!;
  //
  //                         return ListView.builder(
  //                           physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  //                           shrinkWrap: true,
  //                           itemCount: nxteps.length,
  //                           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  //                             return ListTile(
  //                               onTap: () async {
  //                                 var eps = await GetStories().playNextEpisode(widget.story, nxteps.keys.toList()[index]);
  //                                 setState(() {
  //                                   print(eps);
  //                                   audioInit(eps["episode_audio"]);
  //                                   episode = eps["episode_id"];
  //                                   choice!.remove();
  //                                 });
  //                               },
  //                               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  //                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  //                               ),
  //                               tileColor: Colors.red,
  //                               title: Text(
  //                                 nxteps.values.toList()[index],
  //                                 style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  //                               ),
  //                               subtitle: Text(
  //                                 nxteps.keys.toList()[index],
  //                                 style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  //                               ),
  //                               leading: IconButton(
  //                                 onPressed: () {
  //                                   choice!.remove();
  //                                 },
  //                                 color: Colors.white,
  //                                 iconSize: height * 0.04,
  //                                 icon: const Icon(
  //                                   Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
  //                                 ),
  //                               ),
  //                             );
  //                           },
  //                         );
  //                       },
  //                     )
  //
  //                   ],
  //                 ),
  //               ),
  //             ),
  //           ),
  //         ),
  //       ),
  //     );
  //   });
  //
  //   overlayState.insert(choice);
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    audioInit(widget.playLink);
    isPlaying = false;
  }

  Future<void> audioInit(audio) async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

    audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((position) {
      if (mounted == true) {
        // setState(() {
          _value = position.inSeconds.toDouble();
          Duration duration = Duration(seconds: _value.toInt());
          Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setCurrentPosition(duration);
        // });
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((event) {
      Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setDuration(event!);
    });

    audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) {
      if(event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        if(mounted) {
          // setState(() {
            isPlaying = false;
            showAlert(context, "SOng is Completed!");
            // _showChoices(context);
          // });
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("_-_-_-_-_-_ SONG COMPLETED _-_-_-_-_-_");
        }
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("_-_-_-_-_-_ SONG NOT COMPLETED _-_-_-_-_-_");
        }
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
    }, onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('A stream error occurred: $e');
      }
    });
    // Try to load audio from a source and catch any errors.
    try {
      // AAC example: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aac
      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(audio),
        tag: MediaItem(
          // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
          id: 'StoryFy',
          // Metadata to display in the notification:
          album: widget.story,
          title: episode.split("=")[0],
          artUri: Uri.parse(widget.poster),
        ),
      ));

      final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
      Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setCurrentPosition(duration!);
      // audioPlayer.play();
      // setState(() {
      //   isPlaying = true;
      // });
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Error loading audio source: $e");
      }
    }
  }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   audioPlayer.dispose();
  //   WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  // @override
  // void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  //   super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  //   if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
  //     // Resume audio playback if necessary
  //     // if (isPlaying) {
  //     //   audioPlayer.play();
  //     // }
  //     state = state;
  //   } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
  //     // Pause audio playback if necessary
  //     // if (isPlaying) {
  //     //   audioPlayer.pause();
  //     // }
  //   }
  // }

  String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final hours = duration.inHours.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$hours:$minutes:$seconds';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double width = screenSize.width;
    final double height = screenSize.height;

    final playerStateModel = Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => PlayerStateModel(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.03),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 10,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: Image.network(
                        widget.poster,
                        height: height * 0.5,
                        width: width,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: height * 0.05,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    episode.split("=")[0],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: height * 0.03,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: height * 0.01,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.story,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: height * 0.02,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: height * 0.02,
                ),

                Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                  builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                    _value = playerState.currentPosition.inSeconds.toDouble();
                    return Slider(
                      value: _value,
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      inactiveColor: globals.shadowColor,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        final clampedValue = newValue.clamp(0.0, playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble());
                        audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: clampedValue.toInt()));
                        setState(() {
                          _value = clampedValue;
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),

                // StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
                //   stream: audioPlayer.durationStream,
                //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                //     final duration = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
                //     return Slider(
                //       value: _value,
                //       min: 0.0,
                //       max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                //       inactiveColor: globals.shadowColor,
                //       onChanged: (newValue) {
                //         final clampedValue = newValue.clamp(0.0, duration.inSeconds.toDouble());
                //         audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: clampedValue.toInt()));
                //       },
                //     );
                //   },
                // ),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    // StreamBuilder<Duration>(
                    //   stream: audioPlayer.positionStream,
                    //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    //     final position = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
                    //     return Text(formatDuration(position));
                    //   },
                    // ),

                    Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                      builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                        return Text(formatDuration(playerState.currentPosition));
                      },
                    ),

                    // StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
                    //   stream: audioPlayer.durationStream,
                    //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    //     final duration = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
                    //     return Text(formatDuration(duration));
                    //   },
                    // ),

                    Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                      builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                        return Text(formatDuration(playerState.duration));
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: height * 0.02,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showAlert(context, "data.values.toList()[index]");
                        audioPlayer.seekToPrevious();
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.skip_previous_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final currentPosition = audioPlayer.position;
                        final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
                        if (currentPosition != null && duration != null) {
                          final newPosition = currentPosition - const Duration(seconds: 10);
                          final clampedPosition = newPosition.isNegative ? Duration.zero : newPosition;
                          audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
                        }
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.replay_10_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (mounted == true) {
                          playerStateModel.setIsPlaying(!playerStateModel.isPlaying);
                          (isPlaying) ? audioPlayer.pause() : audioPlayer.play();
                          setState(() {
                            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: isPlaying
                          ? const Icon(
                        Icons.pause,
                      )
                          : const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final currentPosition = audioPlayer.position;
                        final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
                        if (currentPosition != null && duration != null) {
                          final newPosition = currentPosition + const Duration(seconds: 10);
                          final clampedPosition = newPosition.compareTo(duration) > 0 ? duration : newPosition;
                          audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
                        }
                        // await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(
                        //     seconds: audioPlayer.position.inSeconds + 10));
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.forward_10_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showAlert(context, "data.values.toList()[index]");
                        audioPlayer.seekToNext();
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.skip_next_rounded,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

and below is the state class

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class PlayerStateModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isPlaying = true;
  Duration _currentPosition = Duration.zero;
  Duration _duration = Duration.zero;

  bool get isPlaying => _isPlaying;
  Duration get duration => _duration;
  Duration get currentPosition => _currentPosition;

  void setIsPlaying(bool value) {
    _isPlaying = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCurrentPosition(Duration value) {
    _currentPosition = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setDuration(Duration value) {
    _duration = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a lot of code, there might be other errors, but on a first quick look:

why are you inserting two `ChangeNotifierProvider`?

Your inner `Consumer` widgets will use the `PlayerStateModel` of the inner provider, but your modifications from your `audioInit` access and modify the `PlayerStateModel` of the outer provider instead for which the consumers will get no updates.

Also as a side note, you sometimes still use the local `isPlaying` of the state object sometimes with `setState` and sometimes not and sometimes you use the `PlayerStateModel.isPlaying` instead. Is this intended?

Comment: at first I was starting to use provider at that time there are many errors and by observing examples from online resources and some by Chat-GPT so I'm not aware that I have written multiple ```ChangeNotifierProvider``` and same for the ```isPlaying``` that want to check that whether is will work or not.

Comment: I have removed ```ChangeNotifierProvider``` from ```PlayingStoryState``` and instead of ```isPlaying``` I have added ```Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setIsPlaying(value)``` and now I'm able to set provider state. but when retrieving state it is not updating slider and duration of audio.

Comment: Please update your initial code snippet of your question with the current changes and ping me in a comment when you are then. I'll take another look at it then.

Comment: see __UPDATE__ answer of mine

Answer (score 0):

### **UPDATE**

So, below is the updated code that works well when we are in current screen. but let us consider a situation that you need to some how leaving the app and revisiting this screen then it will not get updated values. also I wan to implement such on tap event on audio notification that auto navigates `PlayingStory` screen.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:app/model/PlayerState.dart';
import 'package:app/stories/get_stories.dart';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/error_alert.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';

class PlayingStory extends StatefulWidget {
  final String story;
  final String episode;
  final String playLink;
  final String poster;

  const PlayingStory(
      {Key? key,
        required this.story,
        required this.episode,
        required this.playLink,
        required this.poster})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PlayingStoryState();
}

class PlayingStoryState extends State<PlayingStory> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  double _value = 0.0;
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late bool isPlaying;
  bool _isCompleted = false;
  late AppLifecycleState state;
  late String episode = widget.episode;

  void _showChoices(BuildContext context) {

    // GetStories().updateStoryList(widget.story,context);
    var nextEpisode = GetStories().fetchNextEpisodes(widget.story);

    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry? choice;

    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final height = size.height;
    final width = size.width;

    choice = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      print("_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ OVERLAY CALLED _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_");
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.035, vertical: height * 0.06),
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: const Color(0xff838080),
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaY: 8.0,
                  sigmaX: 8.0,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [

                      FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(
                        future: nextEpisode,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }

                          final nxteps = snapshot.data!;

                          return ListView.builder(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: nxteps.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  var eps = await GetStories().playNextEpisode(widget.story, nxteps.keys.toList()[index]);
                                  var lst = eps.values.toList();
                                  setState(() {
                                    // print("_-_-_-_-_ EPS _-_-_-_-_\n$eps");
                                    // print("_-_-_-_-_ LST _-_-_-_-_\n$lst");
                                    audioInit(lst[1]);
                                    episode = lst[0];
                                    choice!.remove();
                                  });
                                },
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                tileColor: Colors.red,
                                title: Text(
                                  nxteps.values.toList()[index],
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  nxteps.keys.toList()[index],
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                leading: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    choice!.remove();
                                  },
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  iconSize: height * 0.04,
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      )

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });

    overlayState.insert(choice);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    audioInit(widget.playLink);
    isPlaying = false;
  }

  Future<void> audioInit(audio) async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

    audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((position) {
      if (mounted == true) {
        // setState(() {
        _value = position.inSeconds.toDouble();
        Duration duration = Duration(seconds: _value.toInt());
        Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setCurrentPosition(duration);
        // });
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((event) {
      Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setDuration(event!);
    });

    audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed && !_isCompleted) {
        // setState(() {
          Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setIsPlaying(false);
          _isCompleted = true;
        // });
        // Show overlay or perform actions on audio completion
        _showChoices(context);
      } else if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.ready) {
        // Reset the completion state when the player is ready to play the next audio
        _isCompleted = false;
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("_-_-_-_-_-_ SONG NOT COMPLETED _-_-_-_-_-_");
        }
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
    }, onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('A stream error occurred: $e');
      }
    });
    // Try to load audio from a source and catch any errors.
    try {
      // AAC example: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aac
      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(audio),
        tag: MediaItem(
          // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
          id: 'StoryFy',
          // Metadata to display in the notification:
          album: widget.story,
          title: episode.split("=")[0],
          artUri: Uri.parse(widget.poster),
        ),
      ));

      final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
      Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).setCurrentPosition(duration!);
      // audioPlayer.play();
      // setState(() {
      //   isPlaying = true;
      // });
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Error loading audio source: $e");
      }
    }
  }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   audioPlayer.dispose();
  //   WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  // @override
  // void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  //   super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  //   if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
  //     // Resume audio playback if necessary
  //     // if (isPlaying) {
  //     //   audioPlayer.play();
  //     // }
  //     state = state;
  //   } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
  //     // Pause audio playback if necessary
  //     // if (isPlaying) {
  //     //   audioPlayer.pause();
  //     // }
  //   }
  // }

  String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final hours = duration.inHours.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$hours:$minutes:$seconds';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double width = screenSize.width;
    final double height = screenSize.height;

    final playerStateModel = Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.03),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Image.network(
                      widget.poster,
                      height: height * 0.5,
                      width: width,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.05,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  episode.split("=")[0],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: height * 0.03,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.01,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.story,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: height * 0.02,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.02,
              ),

              Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                  _value = playerState.currentPosition.inSeconds.toDouble();
                  return Slider(
                    value: _value,
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    inactiveColor: globals.shadowColor,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      final clampedValue = newValue.clamp(0.0, playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble());
                      audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: clampedValue.toInt()));
                      setState(() {
                        _value = clampedValue;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),

              // StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
              //   stream: audioPlayer.durationStream,
              //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
              //     final duration = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
              //     return Slider(
              //       value: _value,
              //       min: 0.0,
              //       max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
              //       inactiveColor: globals.shadowColor,
              //       onChanged: (newValue) {
              //         final clampedValue = newValue.clamp(0.0, duration.inSeconds.toDouble());
              //         audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: clampedValue.toInt()));
              //       },
              //     );
              //   },
              // ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // StreamBuilder<Duration>(
                  //   stream: audioPlayer.positionStream,
                  //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  //     final position = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
                  //     return Text(formatDuration(position));
                  //   },
                  // ),

                  Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                    builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                      return Text(formatDuration(playerState.currentPosition));
                    },
                  ),

                  // StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
                  //   stream: audioPlayer.durationStream,
                  //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  //     final duration = snapshot.data ?? Duration.zero;
                  //     return Text(formatDuration(duration));
                  //   },
                  // ),

                  Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                    builder: (context, playerState, child) {
                      return Text(formatDuration(playerState.duration));
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.02,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showAlert(context, "data.values.toList()[index]");
                      audioPlayer.seekToPrevious();
                    },
                    iconSize: height * 0.05,
                    color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.skip_previous_rounded,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final currentPosition = audioPlayer.position;
                      final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
                      if (currentPosition != null && duration != null) {
                        final newPosition = currentPosition - const Duration(seconds: 10);
                        final clampedPosition = newPosition.isNegative ? Duration.zero : newPosition;
                        audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
                      }
                    },
                    iconSize: height * 0.05,
                    color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.replay_10_rounded,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (mounted == true) {
                        playerStateModel.setIsPlaying(!playerStateModel.isPlaying);
                        (isPlaying) ? audioPlayer.pause() : audioPlayer.play();
                        setState(() {
                          isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    iconSize: height * 0.05,
                    color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                    icon: isPlaying
                        ? const Icon(
                      Icons.pause,
                    )
                        : const Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final currentPosition = audioPlayer.position;
                      final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
                      if (currentPosition != null && duration != null) {
                        final newPosition = currentPosition + const Duration(seconds: 10);
                        final clampedPosition = newPosition.compareTo(duration) > 0 ? duration : newPosition;
                        audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
                      }
                      // await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(
                      //     seconds: audioPlayer.position.inSeconds + 10));
                    },
                    iconSize: height * 0.05,
                    color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.forward_10_rounded,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showAlert(context, "data.values.toList()[index]");
                      audioPlayer.seekToNext();
                    },
                    iconSize: height * 0.05,
                    color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.skip_next_rounded,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope i understand your wanted behaviour correctly. 

You are talking about minimizing your app and then having like a audio player in the notifications of the phone, right? 

Sadly i haven't looked into something like that, so i can't really help you with that for now. The only thing i know of is the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin for a state subclass where you could handle the lifecycle events (tabbed in, or out)

Comment: @Niko thanks for the hint and help. I'll have look on your suggestion